# finding out if console is available

Tags: javascript, debugging

I was wondering, how can i find out with **javascript** if the console object is available?

i have the problem that if i forget to remove a debug output like `console.log('sthg')` i get errors in several browsers, if there is no firebug, or similar, active.

thanks for help

*next to that problem i am interested in all informations about the console object. has anybody some documentation link, or so? is it a standard? and so on...*

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Check the property exists as a member of `window`:

```
if (window.console) {
}
```

> *next to that problem i am interested in all informations about the console object. has anybody some documentation link, or so? is it a standard? and so on...*

Check out the [Firebug documentation for the Console API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API); Chrome and Safari implement most, but not all, of the methods listed there.  There's no standard defining what should be in the console, so you'll need to test each browser to see if it supports the feature.

Comment: what about chromes and IEs console? :-)

Comment: @helle: Like I said, Chrome implements most of the Firebug Console API methods.  IE implements some of the basic ones, like `warn`, `error`, `info`, etc but it doesn't implement them all and there doesn't appear to be a documented list so you will have to try them out for yourself.

Comment: @AndyE could you please explain why checking that the property exists in window isn't as robust as using typeof? Why shouldn't we check directly the windows.console variable or even just console global as in the other answers?

Comment: @matpop: scripts that were written before window.console was a thing could accidentally override the variable with a global called `console`.  That's a pretty unlikely scenario these days so I've edited my post to simplify the answer.

Answer (score 32):

A nice simple and short way of outputting to the console safely is as follows:

```
window.console && console.log('Debug message');
```

Comment: I don't think this is very good because someone may have overwritten console and .log does not exist. You should also check if .log exists and indeed is a function.

Answer (score 8):

here's what i use. bear in mind that i am only half-heartedly supporting browsers with no support for console. and i only ever use console.log(), but you can see how it can be extended to support console.dir(), console.info(), etc

```
var console = console || {
    "log": function(stuff) {}
};
```

I like it because calling it does not cause an error, but it returns [undefined], which i think is appropriate.

Note that many many people before (and after) us have written similar polyfills:

https://gist.github.com/search?q=console+%7C%7C+console

Comment: +1 because I think it's a good Idea. Andy E's answer does exactly what was asked, so he has still the correct answer.

Comment: agreed. this is more of an aside than a direct answer. i'm glad you like it

Comment: It may be worth to say that it works because the _var_ directive is actually processed **before** the code execution.

Answer (score 6):

Defined by [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/logging), IE8 (need to open the developer tools with F12), Chrome, etc but there is no defined spec for it. There is a [console.log wrapper](http://benalman.com/projects/javascript-debug-console-log/) that makes it a very easy to use, cross browser logging solution so if the console doesn't exist your code doesn't explode.

Comment: That's what I was looking for to recommend but couldn't think of the name! Good to know some one else found it.

Comment: what about chromes and IEs console? :-)

Comment: @helle Yeah I guess IE8 did add a console now and wasn't thinking of Chrome. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
try{
console.log("test")
}
catch(e){
console={},
console.log=function(a){}
}
```

just put it at the top of your JS file and then use console.log(); without any worry for browser error, i also had this error in IE9

Comment: Interesting solution. I normally don't like using exceptions to handle flow, but this could be really handy.

Answer (score 3):

I always include this in the top of my HTML-header before I load anything else. Debugging with console.debug is just too long for me. And I like to toggle the usage of these console functions.

Don't know how optimized the code is, but it always does the job.

```
(function() {
    var consoleDisabled = false;
    if (consoleDisabled) {
        window.console = undefined;
    }
    if (window.console == undefined) {
        window.console = {
            debug: function() {
                return true;
            },
            info: function() {
                return false;
            },
            warn: function() {
                return false;
            },
            log: function() {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    debug = (function(args) {
        window.console.debug(args);
    });
    info = (function(args) {
        window.console.info(args);
    });
    warn = (function(args) {
        window.console.warn(args);
    });
    log = (function(args) {
        window.console.log(args);
    });
})();
debug(somevar);
info(somevar);
warn(somevar);
log(somevar);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way would be:

```
if (window.console){
   console.log('do something');
}
```

instead of just writing:

```
console.log('do something');
```

Answer (score -4):

maybe...

```
if (console) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: This would throw an error in browsers where `console` isn't defined.