# How to confirm Firebug is installed in the browser?

Tags: php, javascript, firebug

I'm using PHP, for web designing.
before loading the page I want to check firebug in installed are not in browser, Is there any function in php else how to find firebug plugins is installed or not.

Comment: I have no idea in the least how to do this, but for personal interest, why do you want to check if firebug is installed?  What could you use that information for?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398111/javascript-that-detects-firebug

Comment: Have look @ -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398111/javascript-that-detects-firebug

Comment: php is executed on the server side and firebug is on the client side. one way though js would be [this script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634629/how-to-check-whether-firebug-is-installed-in-mozilla-or-not).

Comment: @jermel and Rikesh Shah I don't think this counts as a duplicate.  Asker here wants to know how to do it with PHP.  It is good to refer them, but this question is a little different.

Comment: I'm more interested in knowing the reason for detecting firebug

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this. However, it's possible with JavaScript:

```
if (window.console && window.console.firebug) {
  /* firebug found! */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is on server side, I don't think there's method to find the client side plugin info. Unless, you can control the browser, then you can detect and put the info in HTTP request, so that server can know.

Comment: somehow it maybe possible to detect the firebug is open or not, for ex gmail detect it when you open firebug and do something in gmail then a notification display something like 'firebug slowdown your gmail account speed'

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there are any possibilities to check with PHP, but with JavaScript: [finding out if console is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946287/finding-out-if-console-is-available)

Answer (score 1):

Not on a normal http request, however you can check it with javascript on the client, then make an ajax to the server with the response and act acording to it. [detect firebug with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398111/javascript-that-detects-firebug)

Answer (score 0):

Since firebug does not expose itself via a request header its presence or absence in unknown to the web server.

You would need some client side js in the page that checks for and then sends the result of `window.console.firebug` to a php script which then associates that result in a session variable.