# Very strange behaviour of IE9 when loading JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer-9

I have a web application that has to load JSON objects with help of jQuery. I am using this code to get JSON objects:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    ...
}
```

As usual, it works on FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera, but not in Internet Explorer (I only tried IE9).

What I found out, if I open the F12 Developer Tools in IE, show console, refresh the page, it works properly. And I think this is pretty strange. I asked some colleges to check and they were able to reproduce this. What changes when the developer tools are opened? Why is it working then?

---

**Edit:**

Example of a JSON object that I receive from my servlet:

```
{"product":[],"signaling":[],"vendor":["HP","SUN","IBM"],"capacity":[],"backup"‌​:[],"availability":[]}
```

---

Comment: Can you recreate this behaviour by using the `$.ajax()` function as well?

Comment: Can you post the JSON that is being received?

Comment: Since it only works with the development tools you might have a console.log or document.console.log somewhere in your code.

Comment: @RyanBrodie It won't make any sense, because $.getJSON is a shorthand of `$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});`

Comment: do you have any console or outputting that need the console to be open? whoops marcus has already said this

Comment: Yes I have some console output, but only for debugging. Engineer is right, it is just a handier method for $.ajax(..). One of the JSON I receive is: `{"product":[],"signaling":[],"vendor":["HP","SUN","IBM"],"capacity":[],"backup":[],"availability":[]}` --> My form should now show all vendors as options. After a vendor is selected, products will be filled by the servlet. When the developer tools are opened, the three vendors appear, but only then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some `console.log()` outputs for debugging, and it seems like it is a bug of Internet Explorer. In my opinion, a browser should work, even though `console.log` is there. This is just ridiculous Microsoft!

After commenting all `console.log()`, it works.

Comment: Not a bug, just a different way of dealing with the console. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6036398/352449) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8883761/352449) for a better debugging method!

Answer (score 0):

If you have any calls to console.log(), remove them.

I had the exact same issue with IE.  Spent hours on this until finally removing any console.log() code and it worked right away. Most frustrating.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Just realized that.  Sorry.

Comment: No problem, just an auto-comment from the VLQ queue. Everybody was a beginner once! Some background on why console.log was causing the problem would be good. Starting an answer with "I had the same issue" is pretty much a guaranteed "Not an answer" flag.